# How to send data from python to flutter app

Tags: python, flutter, api, arduino

I am working on a project that requires data received from the arduino via pyserial to be send to the flutter app.
I have been able to capture the data, however I'm not sure on how to send it to flutter app.

Truly appreciate any help.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to connect `python` to application is `api(application programming interface)`, [this article](https://medium.com/@perrysetgo/what-exactly-is-an-api-69f36968a41f) help you understand better

you can use [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/) or [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) i prefer to use [django api](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

and you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64853113/how-to-integrate-flutter-app-with-python-code)